# How to get the Echo >> symbol?

Tags: text, symbols

What is the character code or way to get/type the `>>` symbol used when echoing something?

Comment: You can enter the symbol with `\[RightGuillemet]`

Comment: I'd never heard of the name "guillemet" for these characters, so I found [their Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet) an interesting read. It also contains methods of entry independent of the [MMA named characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html).

Answer (score 2):

For the record:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Echo", CellDingbat}] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Cell["\[RightGuillemet]","EchoDingbat"]
> ```